# RabbitMQ management

Tags: rabbitmq, celery

In the console pane rabbitmq one day I had accumulated 8000 posts, but I am embarrassed that their status is idle at the counter ready and total equal to 1. What status should be completed at the job, idle? In what format is registered x-pires? It seems to me that I had something wrong =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it's difficult to fully understand what you are asking, it seems that you simply don't have anything pulling messages off of the queue in question.

In general, RabbitMQ will hold on to a message in a queue until a listener pulls it off and successfully ACKs, indicating that the message was successfully processed. You *can* configure queues to behave differently by setting a Time-To-Live (TTL) on messages or having different queue durabilities (eg. destroyed when there are no more listeners), but the default is to play it safe.